# change toggle button by js

Tags: javascript, html, css, toggle

I have this code make one button and get some value from server.

then on load ( init view ) I got value = 1 and I need make toggle switch turn on automatically.

the code as below

```js
var value = 1;
```

```css
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 34px;
}

.switch input {
  display: none;
}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ca2222;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input:checked+.slider {
  background-color: #2ab934;
}

input:focus+.slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked+.slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(68px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(68px);
  transform: translateX(68px);
}

.on {
  display: none;
}

.on,
.off {
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  font-size: 10px;
  font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
}

input:checked+.slider .on {
  display: block;
}

input:checked+.slider .off {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div align="center" id="bit00_3">
  <label class="switch">
    <input type="checkbox" id="bit00_3" value="off" onclick="toggle(this);">
    <div class="slider round">
      <span class="on">ON</span>
      <span class="off">OFF</span>
    </div>
  </label>
</div>
```

so I need some javascript to make value 1 in js to toggle button on. programmatically and if 0 is off.

I need use it on init view only

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, you have 2 ids in the same html page, I have changed the input to `checkbox1`.

Second, the `toggle` function did not exist and was not being used, at least in the example, so I removed it.

Third, I removed the value of your input because you were not using it, if you want to get the value, just use `document.getElementById("checkbox1").checked` or just `checkbox1.checked` (with checkbox assigned to a var)

Just call `checkbox1.checked = {0 for unchecked and 1 for checked}` or just `checkbox1.checked` (with checkbox assigned to a var)

obs: I did not use jquery because I did not know if you are using on this page

```js
  var value = 1;
  //you can put the checkbox in a variable, 
  //this way you do not need to do a javascript query every time you access the value of the checkbox
 var checkbox1 = document.getElementById("checkbox1")
 checkbox1.checked = value
 document.getElementById("checkbox1").addEventListener("change", function(element){
  console.log(checkbox1.checked)
 });
```

```css
.switch {
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
        width: 100px;
        height: 34px;
      }

      .switch input {display:none;}

      .slider {
        position: absolute;
        cursor: pointer;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        background-color: #ca2222;
        -webkit-transition: .4s;
        transition: .4s;
      }

      .slider.round {
        border-radius: 34px;
      }

      .slider.round:before {
        border-radius: 50%;
      }

      .slider:before {
        position: absolute;
        content: "";
        height: 26px;
        width: 26px;
        left: 4px;
        bottom: 4px;
        background-color: white;
        -webkit-transition: .4s;
        transition: .4s;
      }

      input:checked + .slider {
        background-color: #2ab934;
      }

      input:focus + .slider {
        box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
      }

      input:checked + .slider:before {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(68px);
        -ms-transform: translateX(68px);
        transform: translateX(68px);
      }

      .on
      {
        display: none;
      }

      .on, .off
      {
        color: white;
        position: absolute;
        transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        font-size: 10px;
        font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
      }

      input:checked+ .slider .on
      {display: block;}

      input:checked + .slider .off
      {display: none;}
```

```html
<div align="center" id="bit00_3">
  <label class="switch">
                <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1">
                  <div class="slider round">
                    <span class="on">ON</span>
                    <span class="off">OFF</span>
                  </div>
              </label>
</div>
```

Comment: nice that code has worked. thank you for save my day!!