# what is this input name in bootstrap or css?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

This image :

[image]

hey stacks, I want to add something like this buttons to my site. but I don't know what is its input name. you can select three divs and when you click on them they get some shadow in the border.
thanks for your help

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/buttons/ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like is already said, you have to look on [Boostrap buttons](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/buttons/).
But, if you want to overide the button boostrap style for add some shadow, you could do this :

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Secondary</button>

.btn-primary:focus{
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px black;
}
```

Look here : [CodePen](https://codepen.io/airmime/pen/ywevBx)

Comment: There are built in shadow classes as well: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/shadows/

Comment: I used your idea and it was really perfect. but I have a problem. when I click one button and then I want to select another button the first button got disabled. I want to select like 5 buttons with each other.thanks for your time.

Comment: You have to [toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) your shadow, you could take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53401382/11124723)